# 'Conversion failed' error is not captured while executing in C# or in stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
 SELECT 
     B.ID, R.COUNTRY_ID, R.LOOK_UP, R.VALUE 
 FROM 
     BUSINESS_TABLE B
 INNER JOIN 
     MASTER_TABLE1 M1 on M1.MASTER_ID = B.B_ID
 LEFT JOIN 
     MASTER_TABLE2 M2 on M2.MASTER_ID = B.B_ID
 LEFT JOIN 
     ANOTHER_TABLE OT on OT.ID = M2.MASTER_ID
 LEFT JOIN 
     [dbo].[TEST_REFERENCE]R ON M2.C_ID = R.LOOK_UP
 WHERE 
     OT.ACTIVE = 1
```

In the above tables all the `ID` columns are `int` except `TEST_REFERENCE` table as below

```
select * from [TEST_REFERENCE]

ID          REF_CODE(varchar 200)   LOOK_UP(varchar 200)    VALUE(varchar 200)  
----        ---------               -----------             ------------
1           COUNTRY                 1                       FRANCE
2           COUNTRY                 2                       GERMANY
3           USER                    POWER_USER              ADMIN
4           USER                    POWER_USER              MASTER
```

The above example query (entered by users) that I'm validating using C# and inserting into DB (if passed) for further purposes.

And below is error that I'm getting while executing the query in SSMS directly.

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'POWER_USER' to data type int.

But there is no error while executing the same query either by using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` nor in stored procedure. In the stored procedure, I have the query alone inside a stored procedure and executing the procedure in C#/SSMS.

Appreciated in anyone gives solution(s).

**PS:** I know it is because of comparing varchar to int and I have a workaround by casting the values. 
My requirement is to validate similar kind of queries using C# (by hitting DB) and insert into DB only if it pass by eliminating the erroneous queries.

**NOTE:** it works fine in C# (exception raised) when we have only two tables with join conditions

Comment: Well, it seems `MASTER_TABLE2.C_ID` is of type `int`...

Comment: ANOTHER_TABLE is not LEFT JOIN-ed here. Move the WHERE condition to he ON clause to get real LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: No error handling in the storedproc nor in the ExecuteNonQuery(). You get back no information from the success of the command. Try to add it.

Comment: i have found out the error , it is coming because you are comparing varchar with int.
can you tell me what is expected output , so i can post exact answer

Comment: Thanks PeterRing. Is there any other way to validate these kind of queries using C#?

Comment: whatyou mean by "it works fine in C# (exception raised) when we have only two tables with join conditions"?

Comment: @S.Serp I'm validating the queries (having only two tables with join conditions instead of FIVE tables) by executing them in C# and it will throw exception when it fails.

Comment: Can you please show the code in C# where you are attempting to catch the exception?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT B.ID,R.COUNTRY_ID,Convert(Varchar,R.LOOK_UP) as LookUp,R.VALUE FROM BUSINESS_TABLE B
INNER JOIN MASTER_TABLE1 M1 on M1.MASTER_ID = B.B_ID
INNER JOIN MASTER_TABLE2 M2 on M2.MASTER_ID = B.B_ID
LEFT JOIN ANOTHER_TABLE OT on OT.ID = M2.MASTER_ID
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[TEST_REFERENCE]R ON M2.C_ID = R.LOOK_UP
WHERE OT.ACTIVE = 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have this as a workaround but this is one of the example and it may vary. Can you tell me how to capture similar kind of errors in C#?

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are trying to compare your `M2.C_ID` which is int with `R.LOOK_UP` which is `varchar(200)`

```
LEFT JOIN 
     [dbo].[TEST_REFERENCE]R ON M2.C_ID = R.LOOK_UP
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a work around for this by casting it. Is it possible to capture these error in C# for this query?

Comment: @SanjeevKumarR : you can use try catch in stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage.aspx) `SqlConnection.InfoMessage` event occurs when SQL Server returns a warning or informational messageL

> Clients that want to process warnings or informational messages sent by the server should create an SqlInfoMessageEventHandler delegate to listen to this event.
>   The InfoMessage event occurs when a message with a severity of 10 or less is returned by SQL Server. Messages that have a severity between 11 and 20 raise an error and messages that have a severity over 20 causes the connection to close.

Could you try this and check the messages :

```
//SqlConnection connection = ...;
connection.InfoMessage +=  new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);

// ... create a SqlCommand from this connection and run cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ...

void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
{
    foreach (SqlError err in args.Errors)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine
        MessageBox.Show("The " + err.Source + " has received a severity " + err.Class + ", state " + err.State + "\n" +
        "on line " + err.LineNumber + ":\n" + err.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you test this? whats your feedback?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tested as mentioned above using the `InfoMessage` but the method is not executed for the failed query. Also I made the setting FireInfoMessageEventOnUserErrors = true manually even that didn't work.